# How do I evaluate $\int_0^1 [x_0 + (x_1 - x_0)t]^2[y_0+(y_1-y_0)t]\ dt$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I want to evaluate the above for two know vertices $\mathbf{x}_0$ and $\mathbf{x}_1$ where $\mathbf{x}_i=[x_i,y_i]$. If I attempt to directly apply integration by parts to the above without expanding, I end up having to divide by $x_1-x_0$, which could be zero. So is it absolutely necessary that I expand all the terms in order to evaluate the above? Or am I missing something?

Comment: You want to integrate a polynomial... Your only variable is $t$. Do you know how to compute the integral of a polynomial?

Comment: Apologies @PierreCarre ...I may have misinterpreted that.

Comment: @niran90 Didn't read your comment, but apologies accepted anyway! I did not mean to be condescending, it was just to understand how to write down an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Literally, just expand in powers of $t$ and...do the integration?

\begin{align}
& \int_0^1 [x_0 + (x_1-x_0)t]^2[y_0+(y_1-y_0)t] \, dt \\
= & \int_0^1 [x_0^2 + 2(x_1-x_0)t + (x_1-x_0)^2t^2][y_0+(y_1-y_0)t] \, dt \\
= & \int_0^1 \big \{\color{red}{x_0^2y_0} + \color{blue}{\big[x_0^2(y_1-y_0) + 2(x_1-x_0)y_0 \big]}t + \color{green}{\big[2(x_1-x_0)(y_1-y_0) + (x_1-x_0)^2y_0\big]}t^2 + \color{orange}{(x_1-x_0)^2(y_1-y_0)}t^3 \big\} \, dt \\
= & \bigg[\color{red}{x_0^2y_0}t + \color{blue}{\big[x_0^2(y_1-y_0) + 2(x_1-x_0)y_0 \big]}\frac{t^2}{2} + \color{green}{\big[2(x_1-x_0)(y_1-y_0) + (x_1-x_0)^2y_0\big]} \frac{t^3}{3} + \color{orange}{(x_1-x_0)^2(y_1-y_0)} \frac{t^4}{4} \bigg]_0^1 \\
= & \color{red}{x_0^2y_0} + \color{blue}{\frac 12 \big[x_0^2(y_1-y_0) + 2(x_1-x_0)y_0 \big]} + \color{green}{\frac 13 \big[2(x_1-x_0)(y_1-y_0) + (x_1-x_0)^2y_0\big]} + \color{orange}{\frac 14(x_1-x_0)^2(y_1-y_0)}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for this. Note that I tried this approach and the one posted by Quanto below, and the results are entirely different (I have checked this numercally). This is what I was confused about.

Comment: Should be the same after you expand and tidy up my solution; and factorise $$x_1^3-x_0^3 = (x_1-x_0)(x_1^2+x_1x_0+x_0^2)$$ and reduce the fractions in Quanto's solution

Comment: Okay I will tidy up and compare again. I was also wondering how the approach below could be valid in the general case, as $(x_1-x_0)$ could be zero. So even if it cancels out fully with terms on the numerator, the 'cancelling' out part is not allowed in the general case right?

Comment: If $x_1-x_0 = 0$, then the first step is already invalid, since we have taken out the $$\frac{y_0}{x_1-x_0}$$

Comment: Yes indeed, which is what's adding to the confusion. So am I right in that one must $\textbf{necessarily}$ expand all the terms to avoid running into that situation?

Comment: If you want to use the method pointed out by Quanto, then you simply have to consider the two cases separately. When $x_1-x_0 \neq 0$, you are fine. When $x_1-x_0=0$, you get a simplification in the integral. It becomes simply $$\int_0^1 x_0^2[y_0+(y_1-y_0)t] \, dt$$ which is very easy to compute directly.

Comment: Ahh ok I see now. Thanks for pointing that nuance out!

Comment: @niran90 In this situation, there's nothing wrong with assuming $x_1-x_0\neq0$ throughout the calculation to avoid division by zero, and after you finish calculating the integral take the limit $x_1\rightarrow x_0$.

Comment: @DavidH Thanks for pointing that out David! I have tried expanding and simplifying Quanto's approach below but I always end up with a $(x_1-x_0)$ term in the denominator :/

Answer (score 0):

Keep the integration in compact form below,

$$\int_0^1 [x_0 + (x_1 - x_0)t]^2[y_0+(y_1-y_0)t]\ dt$$
$$=\frac{y_0}{x_1 - x_0}\int_0^1 [x_0 + (x_1 - x_0)t]^2d[(x_1 - x_0)t]
+\frac{y_1-y_0}{2(x_1 - x_0)^2}\int_0^1 [x_0 + (x_1 - x_0)t]^2 d([(x_1 - x_0)t]^2)$$
$$=\frac{y_0}{3(x_1 - x_0)}[x_0 + (x_1 - x_0)t]^3|_0^1
+\frac{y_1-y_0}{4(x_1 - x_0)^2}[x_0 + (x_1 - x_0)t]^4|_0^1$$

$$=\frac{y_0}{3}\frac{x_1^3 - x_0^3}{x_1 - x_0}  +\frac{y_1-y_0}{4}\frac{x_1^4 - x_0^4}{(x_1 - x_0)^2} $$